# what does only right bracket in an equation such as b] = [A]y] means?

Tags: math, linear-algebra, brackets, algebra, square-bracket

I am writing a paper that uses one of the equations from an old(1969) paper

Now I have been asked the meaning of a single right bracket?

It seems it's differentiating between one dimensional and 2 dimensional matrices. However I cannot find anywhere any written description of what it means or is my interpretation correct?
b] = [A]y]

[image]

Anyone from mathematical background provide a link to single side brackets and their interpretation?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a computer programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author appears to be using paired square brackets to indicate a matrix, and a single closing square bracket to indicate a column vector.

Let's perform the substitutions (and please pardon my crude rendering of mathematical notation, I don't know how to do it better):

log(β<sub>i</sub>/α<sub>i</sub>) = Σ<sub>j=1</sub><sup>n</sup>(g<sub>i</sub><sub>j</sub>-h<sub>i</sub><sub>j</sub>) log(X<sub>j</sub>)

b<sub>i</sub> = Σ<sub>j=1</sub><sup>n</sup> a<sub>i</sub><sub>j</sub> y<sub>j</sub>

b<sub>i</sub> = (A y)<sub>i</sub>

**b** = A **y**

A is an mxn matrix, **y** is an nx1 column vector, and **b** is an mx1 column vector.